# Taking a picture with the camera and inserting the image into an array

Tags: android, arrays, android-camera

I am trying to have the picture that was taken by a camera from the android device and have the image's path written inside an array. I could have the images be written directly into a folder but how can I get the array to load up each individual image from the array automatically as new ones are added? example Code below

//Camera Button

```
public void CameraBtn(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            , "image.jpg");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

//Array that stores images

```
int[] image = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.m1,
        R.drawable.m2,
        R.drawable.m3,
        R.drawable.m4,
        R.drawable.m5,
        R.drawable.m6};
```

Comment: Use a list instead because you can't resize arrays in java.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a re-sizable array
you will have to add them in the overridden onActivityResult method to your ArrayList object declared globally